# Laravel 5.8 - Validação - passar valor de um input para validar outro

Tags: php, laravel, validação, request

Gostaria de verificar se ha possibilidade de na validação do formRequest passar o valor de um input como parâmetro para validar outro.
Exemplo:
Inputs 'company_id', 'email'
no formRequest gostaria de passar o valor do 'company_id' em uma validação personalizada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

'teste' é minha validação personalizada e como parâmetro gostaria que fosse o valor do input 'company_id', mas desta maneira ele envia como parâmetro uma string com o valor = 'company_id'.

A validação que quero fazer é de e-mail único para o ID da empresa. O e-mail pode repetir porem não com mesmo ID de empresa.

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi o problema atribuindo o valor do input em uma variável e passando como parâmetro conforme imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]